# This ScrollView layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless

Tags: android

Im working on my new project. Im new on Android Developing. When I use this code, it saying "This ScrollView layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless". How can I solve this?

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:text="@string/desc_content" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/show"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Rom_Baslik"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description_text"
        android:background="@drawable/arrowdown"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/show"
        android:background="#000" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/hide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Rom_Baslik"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description_text"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_collapse_small_holo_light"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I wanna ExpandableTextView :/

Comment: It's just a hint, and it says, "It's possibly useless". Because it could be, that you create layout-elements programmatically. But if you don't do so, remove the `RelativeLayout` parent.

Answer (score 0):

If the only child of a [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) is another `ViewGroup`, that makes one of the ViewGroups useless.

To resolve your problem, remove the parent `RelativeLayout`.